# Модули и функции в Python

Tags: python, функции, csv, матрицы

У меня есть код который преобразовывает матрицу из csv-файла  в матрицу состоящую из нулей и сохраняет её в новый csv-файл , мне нужно чтобы код, производящий преобразования матрицы  был выделен в отдельные функции, принимающие исходную матрицу в качестве аргумента и возвращающий преобразованную матрицу через ключевое слово return. Каждая функция должна так же находиться в собственном модуле. Не понимаю,  что именно и куда надо добавить, помогите пожалуйста

```
import csv
m = [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in open('tekst.csv')]

mz = [[0] * len(row) for row in m]

with open('resultat_1.csv', 'w') as f:
    for row in mz:
        print(' '.join(map(repr, row)), file=f)
from matplotlib.pyplot import matshow, show

matshow(mz)
show()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Итого вам видимо нужно сделать три файла.
1й файл называете matrixfile.py
Вот его содержимое:

```
import csv

def GetMatrix(filename):
    return [[int(token) for token in line.split()] for line in open(filename)]

def SaveMatrix(mt, filename):
    with open(filename, 'w') as f:
        for row in mt:
            print(' '.join(map(repr, row)), file=f)
```

2й файл называете matrixziro.py
Вот его содержимое:

```
def GetZiroMatrix(mt):
    return [[0] * len(row) for row in mt]
```

Ну и 3й файл называете как угодно, но главное что бы расширение было .py
Вот его содержимое:

```
import matrixfile as mf
import matrixziro as mz
from matplotlib.pyplot import matshow, show

mzr = mz.GetZiroMatrix(mf.GetMatrix('tekst.csv')) 
mf.SaveMatrix(mzr, 'resultat_1.csv')

matshow(mzr)
show()
```

Всё это должно быть в одной папке.
Первые два файла - модули, в них функции.
Третий файл - главный, в нем сама программа, вызывающая функции из модулей.

Comment: Спасибо вам, можно вопрос, я как понимаю второй файл отвечает за преобразование матрицы, я могу поменять `[[0] * len(row) for row in mt]` на `[len(mt) - 1], mt[0] = mt[0], m[len(mt) - 1]` (поменять первую и последнюю строку матрицы местами) ?

Comment: меняйте хоть что по своей необходимости! :) Функциональность всегда можно поменять и нарастить, ведь главное тут вам было понять структуру.